# If $A$ knows $100$ people and $B$ knows $100$ people? what is the probability that they know no person in common?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If there are $200$ people in a school and $2$ new students join who both know $100$ folks each from their previous acquaintances, what is the probability that they know no person in common?

I cant come up with a way to solve this

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: On top of what @saulspatz said, currently the title and body of the question don't match.

Comment: I am not sure as to how to solve it

Comment: The probability is $$\frac{1}{\binom{200}{100}}$$ which is about $$10^{-59}$$

Answer (score 0):

Call the new students $N_1$ and $N_2$. You need some independence assumption to be able to solve the problem. So assume that the prob that $N_1$ knows the 100 people in a subset $A$ (of 100 existing students) is the same for all possible $A$.

If $N_2$ knows the people in a subset $B$ of 100 existing students, then $N_1$ is sure to know at least one of them unless the subset he knows is precisely the 100 not in $B$. There are ${200\choose100}$ subsets size 100, so the prob of no overlap is $$\frac{1}{200\choose100}$$